# conditional tag in Rspec examples

Tags: rspec

my rspec example presently looks like this

```
describe Zipcode do
  before :each do
    # comment out to use live web service
    @mocking_geokit = true

    if @mocking_geokit
      MultiGeocoder.stub( :geocode ) { mock( Geokit::GeoLoc, :zip => '77005', :city => 'Houston', :state => 'TX', :success => true ) }
      MultiGeocoder.stub( :geocode ).with('00000') { mock( :success => false ) }
      MultiGeocoder.stub( :geocode ).with('123456') { mock( :success => false ) }
    end
  end
```

I want to change it so @mocking_geokit is set based on a @tag. I prefer to not have 2 separate sets of examples, as the tests are the same, just the mocking changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [VCR](https://github.com/myronmarston/vcr/)? It is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand your question (you want to test the same thing twice, once with stubs and once without? Isn't that redundant?), but you can probably accomplish whatever it is you want to do with [filters](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/dir/hooks/filters) and/or [custom settings](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/dir/configuration/custom-settings).

Comment: I want to run the same set of examples with and without hitting the live web service. With mocks is faster, without mocks is more complete. I agree I can "probably", the question is how.